# What can you conclude about $\ker(BC)$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $B$ be a $4\times6$ matrix and let $C$ be a $6\times9$ matrix. From this information what can you conclude about $\ker(BC)$?

I believe from this we see that the dimension of the kernel is less than or equal to $9$ from the Rank-Nullity Theorem. but other than that, I am not sure what other observations can be drawn. Can anyone please point me in the right direction if there are more observations to be drawn?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$BC$ is a $4\times 9$ matrix. It represent a linear application from $\mathbb{K}^9$ to $\mathbb{K^4}$. From the rank theorem :

$$\text{dim} \mathbb{K}^9=9= \text{dim Im}(BC)+\text{dim ker}(BC) $$

as Im$(BC)$ is a subspace of $\mathbb{K}^4$, its dimension is at most $4$.

Therefore the dimension of ker $BC$ is at least $5$.

(The fact that it's a product is not relevant in those affirmations)

Answer (score 0):

Consider all the vectors in $\ker C$. What will they do, when applied to $BC$? Consider furthermore all vectors $v$ with $Cv\in\ker B$. Are there any other possibilities for a vector $w$ to lie in $\ker (BC)$?